# Is there a way to generate the friendly_id only if the validations pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Currently, the `friendly_id` is generated before saving. So, if there are any errors in the form it will generate the friendly ID and reload. The problem is I use javascript to edit the form fields in bulk. I pick what fields to edit by going through the ids. For example,to look for category, I generate the script to look for `photos_61081719_category` The midle part is the ID. If the form reload with errors, this ID turns to the friendly ID thereby breaking the script. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Wait, if you're using before_save callback, then it shouldn't generate this friendly_id if the validation fails

Answer (score 1):

As @JustMichael has stated, using the `before_save` callback should do exactly what you want. Here is the [the API callback documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html). Technically, you didn't say you were explicitly using that callback, so that might be the problem.

```
class Category
  before_save :generate_friendly_id # this code is only called if there are no errors

  private

  def generate_friendly_id
    # ...
  end
end
```

If the friendly id is still being generated, it may mean your validations are passing. If you are actually changing your model's primary key (meaning you are using `friendly_id`'s value for the `Category` table's `id`, you must ensure that this will be a unique value, otherwise the model will pass validation but fail to be created when the underlying database hits a pk not unique constraint.

The built-in uniqueness validation won't work for this because you are generating the `friendly_id` **after** the validations.